# Effect of null in JavaScript string concatenation

Tags: javascript, null

I expected the following script to display `hello`, but it display `nullhello`:

```
alert(null+'hello');
```

Why is this so?  I can change from `null` to `""`, but still would like to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value `null` is stringified to `"null"`, not to the empty string. [That's just how it is](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8), there is no "reason" :-)

Comment: similar to how an empty object, `{}`, when coerces to a string, ends up as `"[object Object]"` (at least in Chrome browser)

Comment: Thanks Bergi,  That had me for a loop for a while.  I will not forget!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript concatenates the two strings using the + operator.
Consider the following example:

```
var a = null;
alert(a+'hello');
```

Even in the above case, the two vars are considered as strings to be concatenated.

In javascript, a default var is initialized as undefined and not null.
Consider this

```
var b; 
alert(b+'hello');
```

.. This will result in undefinedhello